# Retrieving the changes happened in the posts liked by user - Salesforce chatter

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I want to retrieve the changes happened in the posts which were liked by user using Chatter REST api. I know that Can do this by retrieving the likes of current user and going through each post for any changes. But this would make me to hit the api rate limit easily.

Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: do you mean when a new post is added and liked, or an existing post is changed and liked?

Comment: When the current user(who uses the plugin), comments on or likes the post of some one who is not followed by the current user I would like my extension to follow that post. If someone else comment on same post, my extension should notify the user of the new comment.